# PowerShell - ForEach Output to Variables for use with MySQL

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach, output

Probably a stupid question, but either my Googling abilities have deteriorated magnificently - or no one else seems to be asking/answering this kind of thing.

Let's start with what my end-goal is, so we can see how I made it to where I am so far:  I would like to run a script that automatically checks a punch of paths for folder-size.  I would like for it to return the folder-size in GB.  I would then like to import the folder-sizes to a MySQL database I have setup for report purposes.

Surprisingly (and somewhat unsurprisingly), just getting the folder-sizes was a pretty hefty pain, yesterday.  Went through a bunch of different attempts/functions from other people in the interwebs/etc.

So, here's where I ended up:

```
$dirlist = import-csv C:\Users\Public\Folders.csv
foreach ($path in $dirlist)
{
    $name = $path.name
    echo $path >> C:\Users\Public\sizes.txt
    $totalsize = (Get-ChildItem $name -recurse -force | measure-object -property length -sum)
    "{0:N2}" -f($totalsize.sum / 1GB) >> C:\Users\Public\sizes.txt
}
```

This is pretty good, I guess.  It gives me a list of all the sizes, on their own lines.  I just need to assign each size it's own variable.  So, I assumed - like an idiot - that I could just pre-assign the variable in the Folders.csv file, using a "var" column.

So, I did that.

Then I modified the script, like so:

```
$dirlist = import-csv C:\Users\Public\Folders.csv
function Get-FolderSize
{
    $name = $path.name
    $var = $path.var
    $totalsize = (Get-ChildItem $name -recurse -force | measure-object -property length -sum)
    "{0:N2}" -f($totalsize.sum / 1GB) -outvariable $var
}
foreach ($path in $dirlist)
{
    Get-FolderSize
}
```

But this yields the following Error(s):

```
At line:12 char:39
+     "{0:N2}" -f($totalsize.sum / 1GB) -outvariable $var
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-outvariable' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:52
+     "{0:N2}" -f($totalsize.sum / 1GB) -outvariable $var
+                                                    ~~~~
Unexpected token '$var' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

For Reference, the Folders.csv is basically just this:

```
"name","var"
"\\Server\D$\Folder","Folder1"
"\\Server2\G$\Folder","Folder2"
```

**tl;dr // CSV of multiple File paths -> Get Size in GB -> store each size in specified variables**

Answer (score 0):

you can pass loop object to parameter like this :

```
$dirlist = import-csv "C:\Users\Public\Folders.csv"

function Get-FolderSize($objectVar)
{
    $name = $objectVar.name
    $totalsize = (Get-ChildItem $name -recurse -force | measure-object -property length -sum)
    $objectVar.var="{0:N2}" -f ($totalsize.sum / 1GB)
}

foreach ($path in $dirlist)
{
    Get-FolderSize $path
}

$dirlist
```

Comment: Ah, ok - so that will output the $dirlist, but with the variable names changed to the size values.  Which, I'm assuming I can then just add a column for ID, and then it's just another 'foreach' command to get it moved over to MySQL?

`$dirlist | foreach {
query = "UPDATE servers SET Size = '$($_.var)' WHERE ID = '$($_.id)'"
Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query`